# Finding position of the element in array

Tags: c++

How can I find position of the element inside an array? I have following piece of code where I need to test if the element is at some position, however it is not working as expected. I need your help about it.

```
string knockemdead[4], bashemup[4], street[4], newyork[9999];
string car;

    if (knockemdead[i] == car)
    {

        if (knockemdead[i].find(1)){ // tried knockemdead[i] = knockemdead[1] and knockemdead[i].at(1) but all it did was nothing
            fare = 10;
        }
        else if (knockemdead[i].find(2))
        {
            fare = 15;
        }

        else if (knockemdead[i].at(3) || knockemdead[i].at(4))
        {
            fare = 25;
        }
```

Comment: What are `knockemdead` and `car` ?

Comment: knockemdead is an array[garage], while car is a string which represents a car that enters a garage.  string knockemdead[4]   and string car.

Comment: Create a testable example. We can't help you without knowing what may or may not been happening

Comment: Now, what is `garage` ?

Comment: garage is an array. Sorry I meant to write array ( garage ), not array[garage]. It looks like garage is another array in array, but it's not, garage is just an array of 5 elements. @Jarod42

Comment: @AzureTester: Edit your question to show relevant declarations.

Comment: I hope it is now more clear to you. @Jarod42

Comment: [find example](https://ideone.com/cG7N7j).

Answer (score 1):

if `cont` is some form of container of T, and `obj` is an object of T, 
and T implements ==, then:

```
auto iter = find( begin(cont), end(cont), obj );
```

will return either an iterator to the object (or something that compares equal to it), 
or `end()` if no such object exists in the container.

if the container is random-access (`vector`,`array` etc), then:

```
auto idx = iter - begin(cont);
```

will return the index of the found object

`find` is declared in `<algorithm>`, and `namespace std` is assumed to be accessible

A different solution would be to do it 'manually'

```
int idx;
for(idx=0; idx<SZ; ++idx)
    if( cont[idx] == obj ) break;
```

you need to put the size of the container in SZ prior.
idx will have the value SZ if no object was found, or the index if it was

Comment: I can't use c++11 in this case.

Comment: @AzureTester Why can't you use c++11?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method that finds the position. 
Example

```
int findElementPositionInArray(TYPE[] array , TYPE elementValue){

 for(int i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++){
   if(array[i]==elementValue){
      return i;
   }
  //let's also treat the case in which the element is not found in the array
  //this way we can test the output (we know that if this method returns -1 
  //the element is not in the array
  return -1;
}   

}
```

So just replace TYPE with your desired type (String for your case as I can see) and call this method .
For more complex data types (example your own class that might contain multiple primitive typess) be sure to properly override the "==" operator.

Might contain errors , I don't have an IDE to test this right now.Hope it helps

Comment: which language is this? pointers don't have a `.length` member, and containers want `.size()`